# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory - removing sourcemaps still fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, memory, bitbucket-pipelines

Our team has a CRA application and we are using the following script to build locally and in bitbucket pipelines

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 scripts/build.js
```

We are all getting this error now with our source code

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x111336665 node::Abort() (.cold.1) [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
 2: 0x11002f1c9 node::Abort() [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
 3: 0x11002f3ae node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, bool) [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
 4: 0x1101a41d0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
 5: 0x1101a4193 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
 6: 0x1103458e5 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
 7: 0x11034992d v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
 8: 0x11034620d v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
 9: 0x11034372d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
10: 0x110350b10 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
11: 0x110350b91 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
12: 0x11031dc27 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
13: 0x1106d574e v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
14: 0x110a7e499 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
15: 0x110aad486 Builtins_FastNewFunctionContextFunction [/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node]
```

We disabled source maps in the webpack config and its still failing.
We tried setting the following to false in the webpack.config.js file

```
// Source maps are resource heavy and can cause out of memory issue for large source files.
const shouldUseSourceMap = false
```

Using higher than 8GB is not doable with our current infrastructure building using node on bitbucket pipelines which is capped at 8GB of memory.

On a tight deadline with this blocker. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you actually need more than 8GB of memory and can't afford to trim that down in your build process, you can setup a self-hosted pipeline runner that is capable of allocating up to 16GB or 32GB of memory. Then use [`size: 4x|8x`](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/step-options/#Size) to configure your pipeline building step to require all that memory instead of the 4-8GB that are available for public cloud runners.

```yaml
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build
        image: node
        size: 4x  # or 8x!
        runs-on:
          - linux
          - self.hosted
        script:
          - node scripts/build.js
```

More info on self-hosted runners: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/runners/

---

So, yeah, if you give 32GB laptops to your developers and don't require them to ration application resources, your CI/CD infrastructure will need to match that size in order to build the bloatware they will write.

Comment: after testing locally with higher memory limits, our team found that even with 32GB of memory it was still running out of memory on a particular branch. I believe it may be a code specific issue. Not sure how to find that yet though